# multiple of an integer and asymptotics

Tags: asymptotics, divisibility

Let us suppose that we have a positive integer $N$.

We take the integer $\lceil \log_2 N \rceil$. Does there always exist an integer $X \geq N$ such that the following both conditions are satisfied:

1) $X$ is a multiple of $\lceil \log_2 N \rceil$

2) $X=O(N)$

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may take
$$
X= \lceil N/\log_2 N \rceil \lceil \log_2 N \rceil.
$$

Comment: Thanks very much. That was so simple...